# Get particular Button click event using IPC

Tags: javascript, webview, electron, ipc

I am using electron IPC to communicate and capture events from the guest content of webview.(Please refer this [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/201/how-to-send-retrieve-information-and-manipulate-the-dom-from-a-webview-with-electron-framework) for more details about code)

```
<webview id="myView" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080" nodeintegration preload="./inyector.js"></webview>
```

In the inyector.js file, i have used below code to capture every click event:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    ipcRenderer.sendToHost(event);
});
```

The above code will trigger for every click on the page but what i want is to capture a particular button click with some id also want to pass info from that button to my host page.

i have already tried below code but its not working:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   ipcRenderer.sendToHost(event);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**:

i am able to solve the above problem. Instead of using preload file, i have added the IPC in my guest application and use the same code of preload script  to send event from rendered process to main process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button with id="myButton", just add an event listener for that button. On the click event you can capture any info that you want and pass it as an argument.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   var info = myButton.text;
   ipcRenderer.sendToHost('myButtonClick', {info: info});
});
```

Comment: i tried it already but its not working, may be because the inyector.js get loaded before webview render the guest page so it didn't find any button with id in the beginning.

Comment: When you post a question, do add things that you have already tried, so that people don't waste time answering something which you have already tried.